# skrollr: Changing Positions not Working

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I'm trying to use [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) to animate a div from the left side of the screen (left:100%) to left:25%, while fading from 50% opacity to 100%. Something simple like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="height:500px">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <div data-0="left:100%; opacity:.2" data-50="left:25%; opacity:1">
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG<br>
    </div>

    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = skrollr.init({
        });
        </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The opacity change works great. However, the position change does not seem to be working for me (Chrome, Firefox and Safari) - the text stays firmly positioned at left:0%. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post any CSS, I assume there is none. If that's the case, then the element is `position`ed `static`ally, in which case it ignores `left.`

You need to position it `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

This is unrelated to skrollr and a simple CSS thing.